# Oracle - How to cast a reference to subtype?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ref, subtype

I am using Oracle DB and I have this type with subtypes:

```
CREATE TYPE t_foo AS OBJECT
(id INTEGER)
NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE t_foo1 UNDER t_foo() NOT FINAL;
```

I have a table of type `t_foo` where I can also store subtypes of `t_foo`

```
CREATE TABLE foo OF t_foo;

INSERT INTO foo VALUES
(t_foo1(1));
```

Now I have a table with a column of type reference of `t_foo1`

```
CREATE TABLE bar(
myfoo1 REF t_foo1 SCOPE IS foo
);
```

How can I insert a reference of `t_foo1` from table `foo`?

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO bar VALUES
(select ref(f) from foo f where f.id = 1)
```

But it gives me a type error (expect ref t_foo1 but found t_foo)

I also tried to use the TREAT function but it doesn't work (ORA-00904: invalid identifier).

```
INSERT INTO bar VALUES
(select ref(t_foo1) from foo f where t_foo1.id = 1 and TREAT(t_foo1 AS t_foo));
```

How can I have this insert working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your insert statements is correct; you're mixing values and select clauses, but modifying the first a bit gives the error you see:

```
insert into bar
select ref(f)
from foo f
where f.id = 1;

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected REF MY_SCHEMA.T_FOO1 got REF MY_SCHEMA.T_FOO
```

I'm not quite sure how you were really trying to use `treat`; the closest I can guess is:

```
insert into bar
select ref(t_foo1)
from foo f
where t_foo1.id = 1
and treat(t_foo1 as t_foo);
```

but that gets ORA-00920, not ORA-00904, so that's not quite what you did still.

Anyway, this works:

```
insert into bar
select treat(ref(f) as ref t_foo1)
from foo f
where f.id = 1;

1 row inserted.
```